# Real representations of Lie groups

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am looking for a reference that discusses the representation theory of Lie groups, especially the classical groups, on **real vector spaces**. It seems that almost every text I've looked at restricts only to representations on complex vector spaces, since the theory is easier in the complex case. However, for my purposes I would like to know about real representations of Lie groups, since I am working almost exclusively with real vector bundles. I don't really understand how to find out information about real representations from the complex theory.

In particular, I would like to learn about the irreducible real representations of $O(n, \mathbb{R})$ and $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$, especially on tensors. For instance, I would like to see a proof that a representation of $O(n)$ on covariant $2$-tensors decomposes into trace and trace-free parts etc.

Ideally I would prefer a text with a more categorical point of view, but it's probably asking a bit much.

Comment: What bibliography have you tried ? what do you have access at ?

Comment: My university library is pretty comprehensive, so I can probably find almost any text in there. I don't remember exactly what books I've looked at in the past, but among them are Fulton and Harris, Humphreys, Brian C. Hall, and Knapp's Lie Groups Beyond an Introduction.